# Email sent in localhost but not in server

Tags: codeigniter, email

When I try to send emails from `localhost`, everything works fine. But when I uploaded my app to the server, the email functionality doesn't work anymore! I uses a Gmail account.

Here is my `config/email.php` file:

```
$config['useragent']        = 'CodeIgniter';        
$config['protocol']         = 'smtp';        
$config['mailpath']         = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_user']        = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass']        = 'my_password';
$config['smtp_port']        = 465;
$config['smtp_timeout']     = 80;
$config['wordwrap']         = TRUE;
$config['wrapchars']        = 76;
$config['mailtype']         = 'html';
$config['charset']          = 'utf-8';
$config['validate']         = FALSE;
$config['priority']         = 3;
$config['crlf']             = "\r\n";
$config['newline']          = "\r\n";
$config['bcc_batch_mode']   = FALSE;
$config['bcc_batch_size']   = 200;


$config['sender_name']       = 'Name';
$config['from_email']       = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$config['to_email']       = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$config['email_subject']       = 'Email Subject';
```

And this is how I sent an email in my controller:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from($this->config->item('from_email'), $this->config->item('sender_name'));
$this->email->to($this->config->item('to_email'));
$this->email->subject($this->config->item('email_subject'));
$this->email->message($string);

if (!$this->email->send())
{
    $data['success'] = FALSE;           
}
else 
{
    $data['success'] = TRUE;            
}
$this->_example_output('layouts/sendemail_confirm.php', $data);
```

And this is the error I receive:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to
>   ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection refused)
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1689
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1846
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1869

Answer (score 1):

> Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection refused)

It's possible that your server's IP address is blacklisted by Google due to previous spamming attempts... Is it a shared hosting account? A cloud hosting account? Etc? All those are susseptable to stuff like this.

There might also be a reverse DNS lookup mismatch with the domain name and from address, or the domain's DNS might have SPF policy settings that are preventing Google from accepting mail, or an envelop issue with the host-name, or it's using 127.0.0.1 as the originating address.

Also check your php.ini settings to make sure you are using / or not-using `sendmail_from=` and `mail.add_x_header=` the same way on both systems.

Answer (score 0):

Try using smtp host as "smtp.gmail.com"
$config['smtp_host']        = 'smtp.gmail.com';

Answer (score 0):

Use this config options

```
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['mail_path'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
```

And add this line, after loading email library

```
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

Comment: It works for me. Maybe you should check what `rightstuff` said.

Comment: I think the issue is from my hosting plan, as someone mentioned it here before. After I changed the email info to one of my emails in the same hosting, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $config = Array(
      'protocol' => 'mail',
      'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
      'smtp_port' => 465,
      'smtp_user' => 'iskpro.it@gmail.com', // change it to yours
      'smtp_pass' => 'afycon@123', // change it to yours
      'mailtype' => 'html',
      'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
      'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from($from); // change it to yours
    $this->email->to($to);// change it to yours
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);
  $this->email->send();
```

Comment: Can you please explain what your solution is doing. This is not very useful.